# How can I add jquery slider dynamically including slide function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've written a code that runs on a drop down options click to add different sliders

```
$( "#slider-"+layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["localid"] ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: parseInt(layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["minval"] ),
      max:  parseInt(layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["maxval"] ),
      step: (layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["maxval"] - layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["minval"])/10,
      values: [  parseInt(layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["minval"] ),  parseInt(layerDirectory[tag.innerText]["maxval"] ) ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         document.getElementById('price_'+layerDirectory[tag.innerText]['localid']).innerText= "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] ;

 
      }
    });
```

but whenever I add new slider, previous sliders stop working.
what can I do?

Comment: Post your html plz

Comment: html just has a div where I'm pushing this newly created slider div. Hope that helps

Comment: Please share drop down click code?

Comment: it's quite complicated tbh, but the gist is onclick I create a div with id slider_(number) and then add .slider function to that id

Comment: Possibly reason can be `id`. Because `id selector` `#slider` will always select first matching element with that `id=slider`. So you might always binding `slider` to same first element.

Comment: yup, checked that as well...I'm creating div with id as "slider-1", "slider-2" , etc.